# Can't get this div hover to work

Tags: css

I am working on a site for a band. I decided to give stylizing the events iFrame from Bandsintown so it doesn't look so plain. For the most part, I have been successful in altering the code, but am stuck on one minor detail.

I can't seem to figure out how to change the code for hovering over each event. It changes it to transparent and I do not like that. Here is what I have tried for it:

```
.bit-upcoming-events .bit-event:hover{
background-color: #000;;
}
```

I thought this would work since I used that path to stylize the background color of that element.

You can view the working site at www.dismantledesign.com/phantasm - I appreciate any help I can get on this one. You guys are always so helpful.

P.S. - The events I am currently using are not real. I am borrowing Maroon 5's event list so I can actually see something until my friend adds events. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

the transparency is currently being set by:

```
.bit-widget.bit-layout-row .bit-event:hover {
    background-color: rgba(81, 81, 81, 0.1);
}
```

It is more specific so is overriding your change.
Make your selector the same or more specific